# How to retrieve an array of object property in fetch and then pass it down to the second fetch call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component which is dependent on 2 endpoints to retrieve the desired program's name. I have 2 endpoints. The first endpoint returns the list of programs, which is an an array of objects. Currently, it only returns 4 programs (**2 with program id "13" and the other two with program id "14"**). The second endpoint is dependent on these program ids which I somehow need to pass it down to the second endpoint, avoid the duplicates, and separate it by comma. For example:

First fetch call response:

```
{
  "programs": [
    { "id": 1, "organization": {"organizationId": 2000}, "programId": 13 },
    { "id": 2, "organization": {"organizationId": 2001 }, "programId": 13 },
    { "id": 22, "organization": {"organizationId": 2002 }, "programId": 14 },
    { "id": 20, "organization": {"organizationId": 2000 }, "programId": 14 }
  ]
}
```

Second fetch call: **api/v1/program/programlist/13,14**

In the code, this is what I have done so far:

```
fetch('/api/v1/organizationrelationship/organizationprograms', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if(res) {
    _.map(res.programs, (program, index) => {
      fetch(`/api/v1/program/programlist/${program.programId}`, { // this is passing all 4 programId individually
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if(res) {
          console.log("res: ", res)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Desired workflow that I am looking for:

1. first fetch call is successfull
2. then goes to the second fetch call
3. and pass in the programIds in the url
4. *api/v1/program/programlist/13,14*
5. and then I save the response in the component's state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following snippet it should do the trick.

```
fetch('/api/v1/organizationrelationship/organizationprograms', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if(res) {
    // gets all the ids from the response and make them a set to remove duplicate
    let ids = new Set(res.proprams.map( (program, index) => return program.programId));
    // convert the set into and array and the use the toString function to make them comma seperated
    let params = Array.from(ids).toString()
      fetch(`/api/v1/program/programlist/${params}`, { // this is passing all 4 programId individually
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if(res) {
          //here you can now save the response to state
          console.log("res: ", res)
        }
      })
  }

})
```

Comment: thank you so much! This worked out really well. Just what I was looking for. Thank you also for providing the comments.